# No way to make Laravel/Homestead work –show in browser

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Having spent 1.5 days trying to fix this I thought that I might as well come before you for an answer.

Newbie in Laravel, I've been trying to set up the dev environment in my laptop (MacOS, High Sierra 10.13.6).

I've installed Virtual Box, Vagrant (v 2.2.9), Composer & Homestead

This is what my Homestead.yaml looks like:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - test

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

    # ports:
    #     - send: 50000
    #       to: 5000
    #     - send: 7777
    #       to: 777
    #       protocol: udp
```

I've also configured my /etc/hosts file as follows:

```
1922.168.10.10  localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   test.app
```

I've been experimenting with the paths in the `folders` and `sites`, also following different suggestions from forums but, if anything, I get from my browser either:

```
No input file specified
```

or

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Some few additional info:

The [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#configuring-homestead) says that you have to map `folders` to each and every project, but the tutorials out there say that you only have to map it to the folder that will contain all project folders.

I've tried to match the IPs in `Homestead.yaml` and `/etc/hosts` but at least when they were different (`192.168.10.10` and `127.0.0.1` respectively I got the `No input file specified`, which -I think- it means that at least the browser managed to connect to the server, but didn't find the right file.

As for Vagrant, I can `vagrant up`, `vagrant halt`, and `vagrant destroy` without further issues when I `cd` in my `Homestead` folder. I can also `vagrant ssh` without further issues.

The file receiver of the installation of Laravel`composer global require laravel/installer` is named `Laravel` and located in `/Code` and same level as `Homestead`.

All help will be dearly appreciated. Please ask anything else I may have missed.

Thanks so much in advance. I hope this helps future Laravel newbies as well.

Resources used:
Mainly [this tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3HLNJvVzNo&list=PL41lfR-6DnOqzgYCAOIBTnMUFNdLtsKuW) + [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/2) + [this post](https://chasingcode.dev/blog/fix-laravel-no-input-file-specified/#:%7E:text=More%20often%20than%20not%2C%20the,yaml%20file.&text=The%20fix%20was%20to%20add%20the%20relevant%20entries%20for%20map%20and%20to%20.) + a few hours of Googling around.

Comment: I find 2 things a bit odd in the configuration. `Hosts` file contains an ip for localhost which is not a valid ip: `1922.168.10.10`. In the `folders` mapping the first parameter is the folder of the `host machine` and second parameter is the folder on the `virtual machine`. Those should be formatted in respect to the machine they point to ie if you run a windows machine as host the formatting should be: `C:\folder` in the -map section etc. Also the `folders` mapping folder uses a different folder named `Laravel` than the `sites` mapping. Sites mapping is used to define the `Document root`.

Comment: @user3647971 That's a sharp eye.  I've corrected the invalid localhost ip. 

for `folders`, understanding that `/vagrant` is the default Code folder in my machine, what should the paths be?

For `sites`, should I map it to the folder where I installed Laravel (so `Laravel`).
Thanks! :)

Comment: In the Sites mapping the folder should be the laravel public folder which serves as the document root for the application. It contains the htaccess to route all the requests to the framework and the code to start the application.

Comment: As a future pointer, you should always be in the laravel folder(the folder where laravel is installed) when running `artisan` or `npm` commands.

Comment: As a newbie perhaps try out laragon first rather than going down the Vagrant/honestead route, far easier and will get you up and running with all you need with a Laravel auto-installer and take it from there.

Comment: @user3647971 thanks for those explanations. It was a matter of pathways, then. Thanks!

Comment: @Holo I will definitely try laragon. I've taken a look and it seems more adequate for me/newbie than laravel. I'm finding the setup procedures of laravel strangely confusing... Thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: @Alberczik Laragon is such a fast entry point into Laravel and it will provide all the tools required for database management, even Node.js out of the box.  It's a great place to start rapidly.